# media folder on another server using symlink? (Magento)

Tags: magento, symlink

is it possible to have my magento store on one server and have the store media folder on another server using a symlink?

Would I run into any problems if I was to do this?

I don't have any experience with symlinks and not exactly sure how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount second server directory on your first server and than you can created symlink for this mounted point. ssfs is the tool I use for mounting.

But I will not recommend doing this because performance wise it will be slower, but in other hand if you can setup any domain/subdomain on that second server then you can provide your remote media url in Magento's system configuration, just like cdn server configuration. And it will enhance performance.